Prove that there exists a bounded set $A\subset R$ such that $|F|\leq |A| − 1$for every closed set $F\subset A$.

Prove that there exists a bounded set $A\subset R$ such that $|F|\leq |A| − 1$ for every closed set $F\subset A$.

$|·|$ is outer measure. Below is my idea.
Let $A$ be $[0,1]-\mathbb{Q}$, so $|A|=1$. My goal is to show that every closed subset of $A$ has an outer measure of $0$. Every $[a,b]$ is not a closed  subset of $A$ for all $0\leq a<b\leq 1$.So for closed subsets of $A$ we may only need to consider single-point sets or unions of single-point sets. If the union is uncountable, its outer measure may not be $0$; If the union is countable, it may not be closed subset.
My thoughts are confused, what I'm asking is, what do all the closed subsets of irrational numbers look like? If my thinking is wrong, is there another way to construct such a set? Thanks in advance!

Such a set $A$ cannot be Lebesgue measurable, so your example does not work.

I mean $A$ is the set consisting of irrational numbers on $[0,1]$, is it non-measurable?@geetha290krm

It is measurable, so it is not a valid example.
